# Prometheus check if a metric disappear

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I want have make alerts based on a metric which in my case, sometimes, may disappear
Name of metrics count_items returns number every 10minutes if number < 750000 an alarm is triggered if a metric not exists = OK or metrics count  > 750000 = OK
I did

```
absent(count_items) != 0 unless count_items < 750000 - not working
absent(count_items) != 1 unless count_items > 750000 not working
```

Please, say Me workaround path

This way dont worked https://www.robustperception.io/existential-issues-with-metrics
Prometheus version 2